# In lstlisting, how to forbid the upper/lower frame bars on another page?

Tags: listings, page-breaking

Running `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{121ex}% writing 122ex instead of 121ex leads to breaking just after the upper bar.
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tb]
a single code line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

yields a page break just before the lower bar:

[image: output]

Our non-minimal example is a one-liner, too, so it'd make sense

**A**. to put the code with the delimiting bars above and below completely on one page,

or — which is a slightly different goal but also o.k. for us —

**B**. to avoid page breaks just after the upper bar and just before the lower bar.

There might be many ways to achieve any of the two goals; what are the best or the most standard ways? To the best of my knowledge, the documentation of listings keeps silent about the page breaks. (A solution to the goal **B** is more welcome than to the goal **A**.  Our environment: in our non-minimal example, we use Springer's svmono.cls and NewTX fonts.)

For **A**, we tried minipage but don't know how to separate the code from the text above vertically and properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{88ex}
\lipsum[1]
\smallskip% not sure about the standard vertical skip above the lstlistings.
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% causes too small vertical spacing above. Adding \smallskip increases the space below. (Why?)
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tb]
a single code line
\end{lstlisting}%
\end{minipage}\par
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: output for minipage solution attempt]

For **B**, we have no solution. So answers to **B** are overly welcome.

The maintainer has been informed.

Comment: personally I would use tcolorbox to add frames, but beside this: make a bug report to the listings maintainer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Not sure whether this qualifies as a bug formally, though personally, I do consider splitting off the bars weird. I've just pinged the maintainer.

Comment: a frame should stay by the text, lonely lines are always bugs.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer O.k. Though I have already asked the maintainer via e-mail, I've found no official bug tracker for listings. If you're aware of one, please feel free to provide the URL.